# React Js - 'styles' is not defined no-undef Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-redux

Trying to implement Tabs in react.

I have written Menu component as -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import  'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import style from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';


class Menu extends Component {
render()
{
    return(
        <div style={{width:'30%'}}>
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                        {
            this.props.tabs.map(tab => {
                        const active = (tab === this.props.selected ? 'active ' : '' );
                return (
                <li className="nav-item" key={ tab }>
                    <a className={"nav-link " + active + styles.tab} onClick={ () => this.props.setSelected(tab) }>
                    { tab }
                    </a>
                </li>
                );
            })
            }
            </ul>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}    
}

export default Menu;
```

In App.js ->

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Menu from './Menu/Menu';
import Tab from './Menu/Tab';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: 'Home'
    }
  }
  setSelected = (tab) => {
    this.setState({ selected: tab });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App mt-4">
        <Menu tabs={['Home', 'Settings', 'Profile']} selected={ this.state.selected } setSelected={ this.setSelected }>
          <Tab isSelected={ this.state.selected === 'Home' }>
            <p>Some test text</p>
          </Tab>
          <Tab isSelected={ this.state.selected === 'Settings' }>
            <h1>More test text</h1>
          </Tab>
          <Tab isSelected={ this.state.selected === 'Profile' }>
            <ul>
              <li>List test 1</li>
              <li>List test 2</li>
              <li>List test 3</li>
            </ul>
          </Tab>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I am getting below error -

```
src\Menu\Menu.js
  Line 19:58:  'styles' is not defined  no-undef
```

Please suggest.

Note :-

Styles is present at -

```
<a className={"nav-link " + active + styles.tab} onClick={ () => this.props.setSelected(tab) }>
```

in Menu.js

Comment: Where do you defined `styleS`?. Maybe is just a typo. The import has no `s`

Comment: style.tab instead of styles.tab

Comment: Agreed. If typo then should vote to close as caused by typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are importing style from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' and using it as styles. It is a typo.

Bundler didn't find styles definition so it throws an error.

Comment: Issues caused by typos generally are not helpful/beneficial to future readers and should instead be closed.